# Integral of $\sin|x|$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\sin|x|~dx$$
We have two cases: x less than zero, or x equals or higher than zero.
$$\int_{-\infty}^0\sin(-x)~dx+\int_0^\infty\sin x~dx$$
Left side of this sum is equals to right side, so we have just
$$2\int_0^\infty\sin x~dx$$
Now, the integral of $\sin x$ seems to be incalculable.

Comment: The last integral diverges.

Comment: $1-1+1-1+1-1+\ldots=?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for the indefinite integral (anti derivative) or the definite integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$? If it's the latter:

$$ \int_0^{\infty} \sin x \,dx = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \left(-\cos x \right)\Big|_0^t 
= 1 - \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \,\cos t $$

The limit does not exist, so the integral diverges

For the anti derivative:

$$
\sin |x| = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    -\sin x & \quad x < 0\\
    \sin x & \quad x > 0
  \end{array} \right.
$$

So

$$
\int \sin|x| \,dx = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \cos x + C & \quad x < 0\\
    \text{undefined} & \quad x = 0 \\
    -\cos x + C & \quad x > 0
  \end{array} \right.
$$